# Problem with Java classloaders in Tomcat (embedded) when using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, tomcat, jersey

I implemented a Java Web service with Jersey that should run in an embedded Tomcat. After I added JPA (Hibernate), I had a problem that the `@Entity` classes were not found (IllegalArgumentException "Not an entity"). The exception is thrown in class `JpaMetamodelImpl` method `entity(Class<X> cls)`.

Debugging this method has shown that Hibernate knows about the entity class and uses a class loader of type `AppClassLoader`. The Web app also knows the entity class but uses a class loader of type `ParallelWebAppClassLoader`. This class loader knows the `AppClassLoader` as a parent but `delegate` is set to `false`. Therefore, the entity class exists twice, and both classes are not considered equal.

Some version information: Java 11, Jersey 2.37, JPA 3.1, Hibernate 6.2.0, Tomcat 8.5.88

When starting Jersey (in my class that extends `ResourceConfig`) I added the following two lines:

```
ParallelWebappClassLoader classloader = (ParallelWebappClassLoader) this.getClass().getClassLoader();
classloader.setDelegate( true );
```

Now it works. My question is: Is there any better solution to this problem?